# Tautology Contradiction and Contingency

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose we have $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha \models \beta$.

I want to make sure that I understand the connections:

1. If $\alpha$ is contradiction, than $\beta$ is tautology (in the empty way).
2. If $\alpha$ is tautology, than $\beta$ is contingency.
3. If $\beta$ is contradiction, than $\alpha$ is contradiction.
4. If $\beta$ is tautology, than $\alpha$ is tautology.
5. (Regardless of $\alpha, \beta$): The empty set is contingency (in the empty way).

Am I correct on the above?

Thanks a lot!